# Local Wi-Fi file transfer slow on Wi-Fi

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, network-shares, home-networking

I have couple of laptops connected to home Wi-Fi network. All are running Windows 10. I've set my Wi-Fi as private n/w and turned on network discovery on all the PCs. All of them appear in the Network section of file explorer. I have shared folders set up. **All laptops have SSDs**. So HDD isn't a bottleneck.

Now my issue is, when I try to transfer files between two laptops the speed is horribly low, I get only 2-3 MB/s (megabytes/s). All are connected using WI-FI 4 (802.11n standard). The Wi-Fi router is 2.4Ghz, 300mbps, 802.11n. Windows 10 shows link speed as 150 mbps when connect to that network (megabits/s).

When I do speed tests on Ookla I get around 80-90mbps; that's over the same Wi-Fi when I access Internet.

So my question is shouldn't I be getting roughly 150/8~ 18-19 MB/s (Megabytes) while file transfers?

Now if I want to transfer files I put in Google drive and download in the other PC since my internet is fast ~100Mbps. So my internet is faster than my local network.... This what I want to fix, I don't want to use internet for local file transfers.

I want local files sharing to be faster over Wi-Fi and practically I cant connect my devices using ethernet cables.

I have used the least congested channel.

For testing purpose kept the devices close to the router still not even a slight improvement was observed. This is in contrast to internet connectivity where speed drops with increase in distance from the router.

Comment: You should get the same speed (similar at least). I do here. On each Laptop, make sure the Network Connection is vanilla DHCP (no changes or alterations in the settings). Then do a TCP/IP Reset on each device, restart them and test.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer

Comment: Do not use Explorer for transferring files, it's the slowest.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for your response, what can I use instead of explorer?

Comment: @John If you don't mind could you say what speed you get

Comment: I get full speed on my wireless syncing files by Sync Back Pro, or just copying (terminal session - Copy command) as wireless gives me on Internet

Comment: I like the free [Altap Salamander](https://www.altap.cz/), but there are [others](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Do check your router's total throughput. If you have a N300 router then it means its total throughput is 300Mbps Up and Down.
So if 2 clients are transferring between themselves, only in an ideal scenario the router would assign 150Mbps each ~18-19 MB/s as you mentioned.
In reality the router would not allocate all it resources and usually keeps free channels.
You could try a couple of things

1. Try IPerf between the two systems to ensure Windows or your Hard Disk is not limiting speeds.
2. Have a look at Wifi Driver's Advanced Settings and see if they are all compatible with your router.
3. Check for firmware updates for your Router, or if you are willing to experiment get a open-source firmware like Tomato or DD-WRT

Comment: One strange thing I noticed,when I was going throught wifi driver's advanced setting is it has two options one 20mhz band and Auto. No option for 40mhz.. Is that an issue?

Comment: Sorry, one thing I forgot to mention, In addition to laptops, I have some phones and a smart TV connected, So if those are not transferring but still connected, does the router still allocate some bandwidth of total 300mbps to them? Can idle but connected devices slow down the file transfer between two active transferring laptops?

Comment: Being limited to 20Mhz shouldn't be an issue. But Maybe you can find newer drivers. Most modern chips should have 40Mhz support.
Now, On how the bandwidth is split is dependent on the Router Manufacturer and how the firmware was programmed. But yes, some bandwidth is allocated to all devices connected on the network. The more devices you add the slower the throughput would be. Sometimes different models from the same manufacturer have vastly different behavior on how the bandwidth is allocated. Newer firmware is also better optimized to handle different use cases. So your mileage may vary.

Comment: A couple of phone and a TV when idling shouldn't be allocate a bandwidth of more than 1-3Mbps each. Still, I have a feeling, your speeds are an issue with Windows and SMB. Try iPerf to determine the max speed between the two devices and proceed from there.

Comment: Having the option on the router (20 or 20/40) makes no difference here. We have phones connected wirelessly non-stop, and I have two laptop wirelessly connected - one non-stop and that makes no difference. Huge transfers (3 GB Insider Update) are somewhat noticeable, but not seriously so. Ordinary traffic makes no difference.

Comment: @HoverCraft FWIW, I know this is a late comment to this thread but have you tried switching the Wi-Fi connection from 2.4Ghz to 5Ghz? That definitely sped things up when I was using an 802.11n router.